# gpg: [don't know]: partial length invalid for packet type 20

Tags: encryption, azure-databricks, compatibility, gnupg

I am using Kleopatra to encrypt a file in my laptop and would like to decrypt it in Azure Databricks, but failed.

[image: Failed GPG,invalid for packet type 20]

I think it is due to the GPG version in databrick is 2.2.19

[image: GPG version in databrick]

which is not compatible to GPG version 2.4.0

[image: laptop gpg version]

Below is my decryption code in Databricks:

```
%sh
gpg --no-tty --batch --import /dbfs/mnt/TestDatalake/config_decrypt/Test20230105RSA_private_SECRET.asc
mkdir -p /dbfs/mnt/TestDatalake/decrypted_file
gpg --no-tty --batch --yes --ignore-mdc-error --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase-fd 1 --passphrase-file /dbfs/mnt/TestDatalake/config_decrypt/20230104Test_passphase.txt  -vvd --output /dbfs/mnt/TestDatalake/decrypted_file/DTestPGP.csv --decrypt /dbfs/mnt/TestDatalake/config_decrypt/feature_name_mapping_testRSA.csv.gpg
```

Is there any easy way to upgrade the Databricks gpg version or convert the key to fit the GPG version 2.2.19 format?

Answer (score 3):

GnuPG 2.3+ generates keys with an AEAD algorithm (= packet type 20), and GnuPG 2.3+ by default uses this algorithm to encrypt. However, to date, while AEAD is proposed to become part of the OpenPGP standard, it has not been approved yet (see [OpenPGP Message Format Draft rfc4880bis-10](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-openpgp-rfc4880bis-10.txt)). I believe it is not yet broadly supported. Applications based on GnuPG usually still use GnuPG 2.2 under the hood, as you found out yourself.

If

- you cannot upgrade the recipient's GnuPG
- and/or you want to encrypt according to the OpenPGP standard
- and/or you want to maintain compatibility with the majority of PGP software

then use the `--rfc4880` or `--openpgp` flag in GnuPG 2.3+ when generating keys. Both flags can be used synonymously.

---

FYI

Authenticated Encryption with Associated Data (AEAD) modes provide for mixing some additional clear text, or associated data, into the tag used for validation so that attempts to re-use a valid ciphertext in a different context can be detected and rejected.

Comment: Thanks @not2savvy , will try for using  --rfc4880 or --openpgp flag

Comment: This explained the problem well, but I tried both `--rfc4880` and `--openpgp` and the gpg app still seemed to generate a public key that allowed the packet 20 issue. I only ended up fixing it by removing version 2.4 of gnupg.exe and installing version 2.2 instead (pre-AEAD), and keys generated with that version worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to see the version of using

```
%sh
gpg --version
```

I got below output:

[image]

I tried to upgrade the version of gpg using

```
%sh
apt-get install gpg
```

I got below output:

[image]

AFAIK and as  per the output Databricks may support gpg 2.2.19 version only. we can't upgrade it. we need to report it in Microsoft Q&A.

we can decrypt .gpg decrypted file using python package gnupg in Databricks. For that I installed gnupg package in python notebook using

```
 pip install gnupg
```

[image]

I run below code to decrypt .gpg file

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG('<filepath>')
with open('<filename.gpg extention>', 'rb') as f:
    status = gpg.decrypt_file(f, passphrase='<passpharse>', output='<outputfilename>')
    print ('ok: ', status.ok)
    print ('status: ', status.status)
    print ('stderr: ', status.stderr)
```

Output:

[image]

It worked for me. You can try in this way.

Comment: Hiii Bhavani, thanks a lot for your reply and trial! 
Have you imported the private key into <filepath> ? gpg = gnupg.GPG('<filepath>')

Comment: I just added the .gpg file path in <filepath>, I didn't import any private key into it.

Comment: I have tried to set the path and run the code but I got before error~

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtSq1.png

The error still exist even I have used gpg.import_keys

may I know where do you keep your private key for decryption ?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/python-gnupg-gpg-example/) once.